# Flexbox elements overlap on window resize

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid

I am building a landing page with 3 sections (haven't coded the 3rd section yet).

Each section needs to be 100% of the screen.

Top 2 sections have 2 columns each.

I am using Flexbox for this, and everything looks great as long as the browser is in full screen, and the sections have no content. When I start adding content inside the sections, then resize the window, sections start overlapping, especially when resizing only vertically.

When resizing horizontally it's not a problem, since I can switch `flex-direction:column;` to `flex-direction:row;` to get them to stack.

How can I get a 100% view of the section while making everything responsive when window is resized and prevent overlap?

Would CSS Grid be a better option here?

Here's a Code Pen. Please slide the code pane up, then resize your window, and you'll notice how the second section overlaps on top of the first section's button, text, and image.
Code Pen: https://codepen.io/MarwanAK10/pen/eYedLoZ

If you try removing the button, paragraph, and image from the html, then the problem is gone, and on resize the sections don't overlap...

Thanks!

Comment: If you want your content to adjust to screen size, try using `vh` and `vw` units (which are relative to screen size) instead of percentage units (which are relative to the parent container).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@media` queries for different size screens. So you can display everything differently depending on the screen size. You can view the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

Comment: That can affect how sections stack at certain window sizes, but how's it going to prevent sections from sliding on top of each other until the window width in the query is reached?

Comment: You can change the flexbox used or add a declaration for `position`.  (view the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)) There are a million different ways to do this thought.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe put  overflow:hidden on section

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).